# $ x,y,z\ge 0: xy+yz+zx=3$, prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3y+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3z+1}}\ge \frac{3}{2}.$

Tags: inequality

> Problem. If $ x,y,z\ge 0: xy+yz+zx=3$, prove that$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3y+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3z+1}}\ge \frac{3}{2}.$$

By AM-GM, we will prove stronger:
$$\sqrt{3x+1}+\sqrt{3y+1}+\sqrt{3z+1}\ge \frac{3}{4}\sqrt{(3x+1)(3y+1)(3z+1)}.$$
I check it and it seems true. I tried to square both side, but the rest is complicated.

Hope to see more ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Solving $xy+yz+zx=3$ for $z$ gives $z=(3-xy)/(x+y)$. Substituting this in the left-hand side of the first inequality gives an expression that is minimal for $(x,y) = (1,1)$ and equal to $3/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way.

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+3x}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4}{2\sqrt{4(1+3x)}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{4}{3x+5}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$8\sum_{cyc}(3x+5)(3y+5)\geq3\prod_{cyc}(3x+5)$$ or
$$5(x+y+z)+12\geq27xyz,$$ which is true by AM-GM again.

Comment: Thank you. How about stronger ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{5x+4}}\geq1$ is stronger and very nice.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- Going to two variables we get the function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3y+1}}+\frac{\sqrt{x+y}}{\sqrt{9+x+y-3xy}}$$ so the domain for positive $x,y$ of the function is defined by $9+x+y\gt3xy$ and the function $f$ is defined for all $(x,y)$ enclosed by the axis and the positive branche of the hyperbola $y=\dfrac{x+9}{3x-1}$ without this border.

As usual the minimum, --we can verify it by derivation--, is given by the equality $x=y$ so

$$g(x)=f(x,x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3x+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x}{9+2x-3x^2}}$$ and the minimum of this function corresponds to the point $(1,1.5)$ which proves that $f(x,y)\ge \dfrac32$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Piquito I think, a work with partial derivatives is harder than a starting inequality.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg In my opinion, you are the best in MSE on the topic of inequalities and I, on the other hand, am not good at this topic. It is the reason why I used this method. Greetings.

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

By Holder $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x+1}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(3x+1)(y+z)^3\geq8(x+y+z)^3.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$32(x+y+z)^3\geq9\sum_{cyc}(3x+1)(y+z)^3,$$ which is a linear inequality of $xyz$, which by $uvw$ says that it's enough to prove our inequality in the following two cases:

1. Two variables are equal.

Let $y=x$ and $z=\frac{3-x^2}{2x},$ where $0<x\leq\sqrt3,$ which gives
$$(x-1)^2(15x^5+53x^4-2x^3+6x^2-13x+7)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

2. $xyz=0$. This case for you.

About $uvw$ see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: Thank you. Now, I see it is easy by AM-GM